# Difference of meaning in these two sentences

Tags: past-tense

I checked yesterday but **it still has  not arrived .**

Is it possible to write that, does it mean that at the time of writing my parcel has not arrived.

I checked yesterday but **it  had  not arrived yet.**

Does it mean that up to yesterday it has not arrived but at the time of writing it could have changed

Comment: Your placement of *still* is wrong in both. Why don't you **look it up**? And try **yet** for pas encore. Also, you can check the grammar in Word.

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/The-difference-between-yet-and-still

Comment: I suspedt you may be doing a word by word translation from French.  However French uses a double negative "ne...rien"  English does not use a double negative.

Comment: If you last checked yesterday, you don't know whether or not it has arrived since then.

Comment: So past perfect is the only possible choice here

Answer (score 1):

These double negatives are not acceptable in most varieties of English, and should not be used.

Taken at face value "nothing has not arrived" would mean that "something has arrived". But it is a bad and unclear way to express that.

You should say either "nothing has arrived" or "*it* has not arrived"

You would probably use the past perfect, as you are talking about the state yesterday.

> I checked yesterday, but it still hadn't arrived / but nothing had arrived.